# Using Win CMD for loop to pass Char to python script

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to use a FOR loop similiar to the one below to pass a 0xCHAR to a python script?

```
FOR /l %%X in (1,1,255) DO python C:\users\Zoe\downloads\ZOR.py decrypt C:\Users\Zoe\Downloads\encrypted C:\Users\Zoe\Downloads\decrypted\0x%%x %%x
```

Where: the %%X is the Char I want passed to the decrypt function. Presently it only passes it as a decimal via string. ((Should I just write a python wrapper to iterate through the char values instead?))

Where: 0XCHAR is a decimal value for the char.

Thank you in advance,
Zoe

Comment: I think most of the times your shell (cmd.exe) will simply consume the special characters and not pass them through to the argv

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? you can certainly store that kind of thing in a file or something